# How can I pick a random number that has not been previously chosen?

Tags: reactjs

I wrote a function and tried calling it in my JSX and it did not work. The page just did not render and constantly kept loading similar to an infinite loop. My goal is to pick a random number that has not been previously chosen. For example, I have an array of [1, 2, 3]. I pick 2 as a random number, now my only options for the next random number to be chosen is 1 or 3. I can pick 2 again, but 1 or 3 must be chosen first. I'm trying to choose a random number for my Card component so I can randomly display a restaurant. The main things to focus on are the randomRestaurant function and restaurantCard variable.

```
const Game = ({ yelpResults }) => {  
  // Our state for managing our list of restaurant indexes
  const [restaurantIndexes, setRestaurantIndexes] = useState([]);

  // Our state for managing our previous restaurant
  const [previousRestaurantIndex, setPreviousRestaurantIndex] = useState();

  // Our states for showing our Approve or Reject conditions
  const [showApprove, setShowApprove] = useState(false);
  const [showReject, setShowReject] = useState(false);

  // We are only running this at initial render and anytime
  // yelpResults gets updated (only once per food and location submit)
  useEffect(() => {
    setRestaurantIndexes(Object.keys(yelpResults))
  }, [yelpResults, showApprove, showReject]);

  // Function pertaining to clicking reject button
  const handleRejectClick = () => {
    console.log('Reject');
    
    // Turning Reject Route on and Approve route off
    setShowReject(true);
    setShowApprove(false);
  }

  // Function pertaining to clicking approve button
  const handleApproveClick = () => {
    console.log('Approve');
    
    // Turning Approve Route on and Reject route off 
    setShowApprove(true);
    setShowReject(false);
  }

  // Our function to get a random restaurant
  const randomRestaurant = () => {
    // Getting a random index from our restaurantIndexes
    let randomIndex = restaurantIndexes[Math.floor(Math.random() * restaurantIndexes.length)];

    // Preventing the choice of getting the same restaurant in a row
    if (randomIndex === previousRestaurantIndex) {
        console.log('if ran');
      console.log(`prev: ${previousRestaurantIndex}`)
        return randomRestaurant();
    }
    // Otherwise, we keep track of the new previousRestaurantIndex and return the randomIndex
        else {
      // Keeping track of the new previous restaurant index
      console.log('else ran')
      setPreviousRestaurantIndex(randomIndex);
      console.log(`prev: ${previousRestaurantIndex}`)
      return randomIndex;
    }
  }

  // Our JSX that shows our restaurant
  let restaurantCard = (
    <div className="game">
      <RejectButton handleRejectClick={handleRejectClick} />
      {/* Chooses a random restaurant to view in our remaining restaurants */}
      <Card 
        yelpResults={yelpResults[0]}
        // yelpResults={yelpResults[restaurantIndexes[Math.floor(Math.random() * restaurantIndexes.length)]]}
      />
      <ApproveButton handleApproveClick={handleApproveClick} />
    </div>
  )

  // Show Approve Route
  if (showApprove === true) {
    console.log('Approve Render')
    console.log(`Restaurant Indexes: ${restaurantIndexes}`);
    console.log(`Random Restaurant Index: ${restaurantIndexes[Math.floor(Math.random() * restaurantIndexes.length)]}`);
    return restaurantCard;
    // Show Reject Route
  } else if (showReject === true) {
      console.log('Reject Render')
      console.log(`Restaurant Indexes: ${restaurantIndexes}`);
      return restaurantCard;
  // If yelpResults does not have data for some reason this is our error handling content
  } else if (Object.keys(yelpResults).length === 0) {
    console.log('Error Handling')
    console.log(`Restaurant Indexes: ${restaurantIndexes}`);
    return (
      <div>
        Website was refreshed, you have to click "Home" and restart.
      </div>
    )
    // Our initial render, meaning no buttons were clicked and no error
  } else {
      console.log('Initial Render')
      console.log(`Restaurant Indexes: ${restaurantIndexes}`);
      return restaurantCard; 
  }
};
```

Comment: So numbers can be reselected so long as they are not equal to the last number chosen? I.E. 2 is chosen, 2 cannot be chosen again until 1 or 3 are chosen? Where is `randomRestaurant` called? Can you provide a more complete code example?

Comment: Yup! randomRestaurant is called in the Card component (yelpResults={yelpResults[randomRestaurant()]}, this did not work for me though. Yeah, give me a second, I will post the whole component.

Comment: You are calling `setPreviousRestaurantIndex(randomIndex);` from the function that returns the JSX to render. This means that on each render it will re-set some state, and thus will re-render again. Thus, infinite loop.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Thanks! That makes more sense to me now. Do you have any suggestions as to what I can do?